# R lubridate seeing the wrong number of rows

Tags: r, lubridate

Here is the dataframe that I am using. I'm only including the first six rows. The error message that I'm receiving is the same with this smaller section of the data.

```
structure(list(Date.time = c("3/3/22 16:03", "3/4/22 23:41", 
"3/14/22 16:32", "3/23/22 11:44", "3/23/22 13:02", "3/23/22 13:14"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm using the `lubridate` library and I'm trying to convert this column which is an a 'm/d/y hms' format (Excel) into the 'ymd' format that R prefers.

```
library(lubridate)
```

I'm trying to create a new variable that is the ymd format and I'm specifying that lubridate is looking at the mdy hms.

```
file$Date.time2 <- lubridate::ymd(file$Date.time, "mdy_hms")
```

However, I get this error message.

```
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date.time2, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 7 rows, data has 6
```

I look at the length of this data frame and it does have six rows, as I expect, since I used the `head()` function.

```
length(file$Date.time) # evaluates to 6
```

I can also confirm that the class of this file is a dataframe

```
class(file) # dataframe
```

The full range of the data had 8077 columns and lubridate is telling is giving me the same error message saying the replacement has 8078 rows.

I tried running the code in both of these ways, thinking that maybe the error message would go away if I used a new vector instead of the same one.

```
file$Date.time <- lubridate::ymd(file$Date.time, "mdy_hms")
file$Date.time2 <- lubridate::ymd(file$Date.time, "mdy_hms")
```

Comment: The `ymd` implies `year, month, day`.  Your column seems to be in `month, day, year` followed by hour, month.  So use `as.Date(mdy_hm(file$Date.time))#
[1] "2022-03-03" "2022-03-04" "2022-03-14" "2022-03-23" "2022-03-23" "2022-03-23"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no seconds in the list's strings, so you need to use the lubridate function without seconds in it:

```r
library(lubridate)

file <- structure(list(Date.time = c("3/3/22 16:03", "3/4/22 23:41", 
"3/14/22 16:32", "3/23/22 11:44", "3/23/22 13:02", "3/23/22 13:14"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

file$Date.time2 <- lubridate::mdy_hm(file$Date.time)
```

Here's a useful cheatsheet with these functions: https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/lubridate.pdf